# Django/Mezzanine: Unable to display model's data into Template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, mezzanine

After many try and error, I unable to get the model display into the template, I have try TemplateTags or using view, maybe I have miss out some step...

I have created a Page through mezzanine name "customer data" (url as customer-data), and then create a template name "customer-data.html"

**models.py**

```
class CustomerData(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Contact")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="First Name")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Last Name")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Email")
    address = models.TextField(max_length=200, help_text="Address")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(user_model_name, verbose_name="Author")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Customer")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Customers")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s (%s)" % (self.first_name, self.last_name, self.number)
```

**views.py**

```
def customer_data(request):
  customer_data_list = CustomerData.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'customer-data.html', {'customer_data_list': customer_data_list})
```

**cust_tags.py**

```
@register.as_tag
def customer_data(*args):
    data = CustomerData.objects.all()
    return list(data)
```

**customer-data.html**

```
{% block main %}
{{ page.description }}
<div class='contentWrapper'>

    {% for custdata in customer_data_list %}
    {{ custdata.first_name }}
    <br/>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any great example using template tags or views will be great help, thank you in advance.

Comment: the templatetag is not needed (and it should be `.objects` lowercase). what error do you get?  are you sure you have data in `CustomerData` model?

Comment: the ".objects" my bad, but change to lowercase after I post the question, no data also. and Im sure there is data in CustomerData model. 

Is there a need to add something to urls.py?

Comment: you said you created a `Page` in mezzanine, but then your code just shows a regular Django view and template. I don't know mezzanine, but are you sure your view code and template are even getting used?

Comment: if you just want to use a regular Django view like you made (which should work) then yes you need something in urls.py to connect the view to a url where you can access it.  suggest follow the Django tutorial and docs